# Custom Coding Standard for PHP_CodeSniffer in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, phpcodesniffer

I'm using PHP_CodeSniffer via command line already, respecting my custom rule set located in the project root at `.phpcs.xml`

Now I'm trying to integrate the sniffer as inspection in PhpStorm.

- First, I had to add `/private` to my Docker shared directories
- Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Quality Tools has option `By default project interpreter` set. In the configuration for PHP_CodeSniffer, the paths to phpcs and phpcbf have been specified & validated
- Settings - Editor -> Inspecions -> PHP_CodeSniffer validation has been enabled.

When I select e.g. `PSR-12` as coding standard, the inspections seem to work.

- How can I get my custom `.phpcs.xml` instead? Trying to select `Custom` and provide the absolute path to my file returns error:
  `phpcs: ERROR: the "<path>/.phpcs.xml" coding standard is not installed. The installed coding standards are MySource, PEAR, PSR1, PSR12, PSR2, Squiz and Zend`

I'm using latest version of PhpStorm (`2020.3.2`), PHP_CodeSniffer `3.5.8`

I hope someone could tell where things are going wrong.

Comment: What actual path to custom ruleset file did you specify in the Inspection settings -- a local or remote one? Please try specifying a local one if you have not tried that yet. Since 2020.3, it should be a supported option: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-34780

Comment: @duck_in_hat Thanks! I've got it working by adding the .phpcs.xml file to the path mappings (Languages & Frameworks -> PHP -> Path mappings).